# ModuleNotFoundError python : No module named 'project.utils'

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
└── Project
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── main.py
    ├── utils.py
    └── auth
        ├── __init__.py
        └── users.py
```

In my users.py file, I want to import data from project/utils.py, but when I am running imports it says module not found.
/users.py

```
from project.utils import data    #have tried
from .. import utils              #have tried
```

it will be great if anyone can tell me how do I make my project globally available so I can import stuff directly from it.

Comment: ```from Project.utils import data``` Try this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Importing modules from parent folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714063/importing-modules-from-parent-folder)

Comment: have tried lowercase, nothing works, can you please create a similar file structure and check if it works on your machine.